# Unable to create table next time in android under same database

Tags: android

I am creating an Android application for hotel, for that I gone through step by step. The steps are as follows:

1) First I Display Category Names and Save It In Table, For that I created the table.

2) Now I want sub category product list should use the same database that I use earlier for category name but the problem is that oncreate method calls only one that's why it create table only at first time when I run my application first time.

Now My question is that How can I create table according to my  requirement in android application? Please suggest me the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Clean your app data. Either use App manager or just uninstall and reinstall. The old database will be removed and `SQLiteOpenHelper` `onCreate()` will be called again.

For released versions of the app, increase the database version number and implement relevant schema migration code in `onUpgrade()` callback.